# Synonymize [cyclic-reference/dependency] with their [circular-*] counterparts

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

There are two pairs of very similar tags: `cyclic/circular-reference/dependency`. An overview of these tags:

| tag | wiki | watchers | questions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency) | > circular dependency is a relation between two or more modules which either directly or indirectly depend on each other to function properly. | 23 | 1.5k |
| [cyclic-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-dependency) | > Cyclic Dependency occurs when objects form an infinite recurring dependency graph. The head points to the tail and the tail points to the head. | 1 | 116 |
|  |  |  |  |
| [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference) | > A circular reference is a series of references where the last object references the first, resulting in a closed loop. | 6 | 687 |
| [cyclic-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-reference) | > A cyclic reference is established if object A holds a reference to B while B holds a reference to A. | 3 | 139 |

It is easy to see that each separated pair means practically the same and I think the numbers show which should be the main from each pair. To make it clear, I'm suggesting the following synonym directions:

- [cyclic-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-dependency) -> [circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency)
- [cyclic-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-reference) -> [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference)

It might make sense to change/merge the `-dependency` wiki to make it more general (and not module-specific).

---

From the usage guidance it's easy to see that actually all 4 are very similar, but I thought that as a first step the obvious redundancy can be eliminated and if/when that happens a follow-up merge can be done between the `-dependency` and `-reference` tags.

Comment: Surely we just need four synonyms 1. circular-dependency -> cyclic-dependency 2. cyclic-dependency -> circular-reference 3. circular-reference -> cyclic-reference 4.cyclic-reference -> circular-dependency.

Comment: @VLAZ this is the way.